# Send Speech.Synthesizer to a specific Device

Tags: c#, audio, text-to-speech, cscore

I'm using Microsoft Speech Synthesis and want to redirect the output to the output audio device of my choosing.

So far I have the following code:

```
SpeechSynthesizer speechSynthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer();
speechSynthesizer.SpeakAsync("Yea it works!");
```

Currently I'm using:

```
speechSynthesizer.SetOutputToDefaultAudioDevice();
```

but I actually want to send it to the device of my choosing.  I am looking for a cscore example for how to direct the output device of my choice.  I see that I can use:

```
speechSynthesizer.SetOutputToWaveStream();
```

This takes a "Stream", but I don't know how to feed it that.

Thanks.

Comment: So you've got the data in a `Stream`? In which format is the data in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a [MemoryStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream(v=vs.110).aspx) and attach it to CSCore's [WaveOut](http://filoe.github.io/cscore/sharpDox/1.2.0-release/#type/WaveOut) class. WaveOut requires an [IWaveSource](http://filoe.github.io/cscore/sharpDox/1.2.0-release/#type/IWaveSource) argument, so you can use CSCore's [MediaFoundationDecoder](http://filoe.github.io/cscore/sharpDox/1.2.0-release/#type/MediaFoundationDecoder) to convert the wave stream from [SpeechSynthesizer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer(v=vs.110).aspx). I made a little console application to illustrate:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;
using CSCore;
using CSCore.MediaFoundation;
using CSCore.SoundOut;

namespace WaveOutTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            using (var speechEngine = new SpeechSynthesizer())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Available devices:");
                foreach (var device in WaveOutDevice.EnumerateDevices())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", device.DeviceId, device.Name);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("\nEnter device for speech output:");
                var deviceId = (int)char.GetNumericValue(Console.ReadKey().KeyChar);

                speechEngine.SetOutputToWaveStream(stream);
                speechEngine.Speak("Testing 1 2 3");

                using (var waveOut = new WaveOut { Device = new WaveOutDevice(deviceId) })
                using (var waveSource = new MediaFoundationDecoder(stream))
                {
                    waveOut.Initialize(waveSource);
                    waveOut.Play();
                    waveOut.WaitForStopped();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Very concise and helpful response - much appreciated!